# Deploying App in iOS device - .sql file is zero bytes

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, xcode4

I am attempting to test my app on an iPad and iPhone. The app includes a small SQLite database file, which locally on my Mac is 8 bytes, but when I deploy and run the app on my iOS device, the .sql file is zero bytes.

I initially read the SQL file (database) and discovered that the file is empty, i.e zero bytes.

Has anyone else come across this issue?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you mean that the pointer to the file is nil?

Comment: hey, did you solve this problem? i have a same one

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to update/edit the database file. Then you need to copy it in the `document` folder. `NSBundle` elements are not editable. That may be the reason.

Comment: Well, initially I am trying to query the database with a SELECT statement. I discovered that there is no data in the database and the file is zero bytes.

Comment: Can you post the code used to read the sqlite file and database.

Answer (score 0):

In that first of all you create database which is put into the resource folder but that data is not copy into the document folder for that you need to following code to copy .rsd file into document folder.

```
NSString *local=[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Stock" ofType:@"rsd"];
```

more detail about that database Download the example [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/nimitparekh/files/ADD%20Update%20Delete%20Database/arratAddRemoveDatabase.zip/download).